# Search in remote (proxy) repositories in Nexus/Artifactory UI

Tags: java, maven, artifactory, nexus

In the Nexus 2 UI, we often use the feature to search through all repositories, may they be hosted or proxy. This means that a search for "log4j" will reveal all log4j artifacts available in MavenCentral, may they be cached or not.

Today I learned that Nexus 3 does *not* have this feature (which actually astonished my colleagues and me).

Does Artifactory have such a feature?

Can it search through remote repositories (like Jboss, Atlassian, MavenCentral,...) in the UI?

Comment: the https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Smart+Remote+Repositories said that it is able to browse even if none have been cached in your instance of Artifactory, if the remote repository is an another instance of Artifactory.

Comment: Can see an option to search the local Artifactory, and externally on [JCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter) here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search one remote repository through the UI - **jcenter**.

There is no option to search other repositories like you suggested that i know of. But the good news is - taken directly from jfrogs homepage:

> "jcenter is the largest Java Repository on earth, so whatever is
>   available on Maven Central is available on jcenter as well."
>   -- https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/why-should-i-use-jcenter-over-maven-central/

Read more about how to use it here:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Searching+for+Artifacts#SearchingforArtifacts-JCenter

Comment: I still wonder why Nexus 2 has this feature and others don't ... maybe we should just use Nexus 2 for Maven development for the next 1-2 years and hope that something equally good is created in the meantime...

Comment: We have started a POC where we try to transition to Azure DevOps (Former VSTS/TFS). They have a section for Artifacts which is kind of neat. There it is possible to add different Upstream sources to a feed, but i don't think it is searchable from the UI however :/